# Flask error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'hello' (C:\Users\admin\flask_stuff\venv\hello.py)' when I try to create an SQL Database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm somewhat new to Flask in Python and I'm following a YouTube tutorial by Corey Schafer. I'm currently on the 4th video in his tutorial, where he sets up a database with Flask SQLAlchemy. I have already entered the virtual environment for my app and ran the command `python`, and after that I use the command `from hello import db` (my app is called hello.py). However, when I run it, this is the error I get in my command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'hello' (C:\Users\admin\flask_stuff\venv\hello.py)
```

I've tried to run the commands in my IDE itself (Visual Studio Code), but it doesn't seem to work there either. In VS Code, this is the issue I get instead when I run from Powershell:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Coding\flask_stuff\venv\hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

How can I fix this issue? The operating system I am running is Windows 10 64-bit.

EDIT: Here is my code.

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '3a3b2e821615d1661d6a0ff47b29cbdc'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"


posts = [
    {
        'author': 'QuadCore',
        'title': 'My First Post',
        'content': 'My first post content',
        'date_posted': 'February 2nd, 2021'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Mr.Names',
        'title': 'Computers 101',
        'content': 'My 2nd post',
        'date_posted': 'January 15th, 2021'
    }
]

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')

@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'{form.username.data} account creation successful.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'admin@blog.com' and form.password.data == 'password':
            flash('Login successful!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login unsuccessful. Please check your information.', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move the `hello.py` out of the virtual environment directory. In your case, move your `hello.py` to `C:\Coding\flask_stuff` instead of `C:\Coding\flask_stuff\venv`. After that you can run `python` (with virtual environment activated) in the directory `C:\Coding\flask_stuff`.

Also, if you want to run the program in VSCode, you might have to configure the python interpreter in VSCode. To do that, you should make a directory named `.vscode/` in your `C:\Coding\flask_stuff`. Make a file named `settings.json` in that folder with the following:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "./venv/bin/python.exe"
}
```

You can refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask.

To solve your first problem, your `hello.py` may look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# your custom routes...
```

You should assign `SQLAlchemy(app)` to `db`.

Hope that will work ;-)

Comment: Hi, I tried your solutions, but I was still unable to fix the issue. I tried moving hello.py out of my virtual environment, and I also set up a new one, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Does anything change? Please show me your hello.py so that I can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Sure, I will update my post to include it.

Comment: The code seems correct. It should work. But there seems to be **two** files(`C:\Users\admin\flask_stuff\hello.py` and `C:\Coding\flask_stuff\hello.py`). Are they the same?

Comment: Ah, right! I just deleted the duplicated file. However, I'm getting a new error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'`. I already tried setting my FLASK_APP to hello.py and also following the steps above again by moving hello.py out of my virtual environment.

Comment: You should run the `python` command in the `C:\Coding\flask_stuff` directory, or the python interpreter cannot find it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my `cd` directory to ` C:\Coding\flask_stuff` and it seemed to work. I just have a small question. So to make this work, I had to move my hello.py, forms.py (which handled the login and registration screen, I imported it as `from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm`), main.css (handling the css properties in my static folder), and my templates folder out of my virtual environment. Could this cause any issues in the future if I develop more complex applications?

Comment: It won't cause issues at this moment. Actually, more complex flask applications' structures will be very different from small ones. They will use `blueprints` to separate different parts of project. You will see how blueprints work when you learn more about flask :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change your package structure and then set up your db configurations in `__init__.py`. Assuming `MyFlaskPackage` is your main package, its `__init__.py` should handle your database configs, login miscellenous etc.

```
from flask import Flask
#All Necessary Imports
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '3a3b2e821615d1661d6a0ff47b29cbdc'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'

from MyFlaskPackage import routes
```

By organizing your routes, models, forms as individual files, you get clean code. In your `models.py` you will have to say:

```
from datetime import datetime
from .__init__ import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

This would clean up your errors.(Hopefully)